# Sort a list of dictionaries of dates by value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to sort the values with current year.

Current year values should show first.

```
mdlist = [{0:'31 Jan 2022', 1:'', 2:'10 Feb 2022'},
          {0:'10 Feb 2021', 1:'20, Feb 2021', 2:''}, 
          {0:'10 Feb 2022', 1:'10 Feb 2022', 2:'10 Feb 2022'}]
```

```
mdlist = sorted(mdlist, key=lambda d:d[0])
```

but it is not working as expected

expected output:

```
mdlist = [{0:'31 Jan 2022', 1:'', 2:'10 Feb 2022'},
          {0:'10 Feb 2022', 1:'10 Feb 2022', 2:'10 Feb 2022'},
          {0:'10 Feb 2021', 1:'20 Feb 2021', 2:''}]
```

Comment: How does the input map to the output?

Comment: You're sorting the date as a string, not as a date. You need to parse it and compare the dates.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark thanks for your reply...current year 2022 records are coming first

Comment: Also, there are no commas in your dictionary

Comment: All the 2022 values, followed by all of the non-2022 values? Any rules on ordering within that group?

Comment: Also, can records contain a mix of 2021 and 2022 dates, and if so, how should those be handled?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark "All the 2022 values, followed by all of the non-2022 values? Any rules on ordering within that group?"
ans: if value of 0 is 2022 then other values also be in 2022. no ordering within the group

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark records will not be in mix values

Comment: (1) does the sorting only depend on the value under key=0? (2) Is it descending on the year but ascending in a given year (`31 Jan 2022` comes before `10 Feb 2022`)?

Comment: @enke yes sorting only depends on the value under key = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could leverage the fact that these are datetimes by using the `datetime` module and sort it by the years in descending order and the month-days in ascending order:

```
from datetime import datetime
def sorting_key(dct):
    ymd = datetime.strptime(dct[0], "%d %b %Y")
    return -ymd.year, ymd.month, ymd.day

mdlist.sort(key=sorting_key)
```

Output:

```
[{0: '31 Jan 2022', 1: '', 2: '10 Feb 2022'},
 {0: '10 Feb 2022', 1: '10 Feb 2022', 2: '10 Feb 2022'},
 {0: '10 Feb 2021', 1: '20 Feb 2021', 2: ''}]
```

Comment: i am getting none as a response

Comment: @sruthi the sorting is done in place, so you can `print(mdlist)` to see the effects

Answer (score 0):

Use a `key` function that returns `0` if the year is `2022`, `1` otherwise. This will sort all the 2022 dates first.

```
firstyear = '2022'
mdlist = sorted(mdlist, key=lambda d: 0 if d:d[0].split()[-1] == firstyear else 1)
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but year will not be static..it might be 2023 or 2024 or 2020...data will come from database

Comment: Replace `'2022'` with the variable that contains the year you want first.

Comment: I'm getting invalid sytax error

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted `d:` from the lambda.